# Aligning 2 labels in a uitableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout

Im presenting 2 labels in a tableview cell, I want the right label to align with the top of the left label, but it always aligns with the middle. I tried many auto layout constraints and I can't seem to get it to work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the right label:

```
[rightLabel sizeToFit];
```

This will set the label height to fit its content, so it will not be centered in the middle, it will start from top.

Comment: Labels don't have content size attribute as far as I know